# Why does XML:Simple complain that "No element found"?

Tags: xml, perl

I'm trying to execute a simple Perl program that uses [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Simple) to print out the data from an XML file.
However, the error I'm getting is :

```
no element found at line 15, column 0, byte 308 at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.0/i386-linux-thread-multi/XML/Parser.pm line 185
```

The XML file is as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<customer-data>
<customer>
<first_name>Frank</first_name>
<last_name>Sanbeans</last_name>
<dob>3/10</dob>
<email>frank@example.com</email>
</customer>
<customer>
<first_name>Sandy</first_name>
<last_name>Sanbeans</last_name>
<dob>4/15</dob>
<email>sandy@example.com</email>
</customer>
```

And, my perl code is :

```
use strict;
use XML::Simple;

my $xml = XMLin('./test.xml',forcearray => 1);
foreach my $customer (@{$xml->{customer}}) {
  print "Name: $customer->{first_name}->[0] ";
  print "$customer->{last_name}->[0]\n";
  print "Birthday: $customer->{dob}->[0]\n";
  print "E-mail Address: $customer->{email}->[0]\n";
}
```

How can this be fixed ?

Thank You.

Answer (score 7):

Need a closing customer-data tag at the end of the document to make it well formed. That's why the parser barfs at the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

A better question would be, Given an error of that nature, how can you find where the error in the data file is? It gives a line number and column number, but in most cases the column number will be in the thousands and does not exist in the file. My answer to that question is, Use this code when you want to find where the error is:

```
use XML::SAX;
use XML::LibXML::SAX;
$XML::Simple::PREFERRED_PARSER = 'XML::LibXML::SAX';
```

But comment it out once you've located the error, because XML::SAX is too fussy to actually parse any real XML.